How to maximize the variance of a subset of integers?
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$Given the set of numbers $\Omega := \{1, \ldots, n\}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, how can I choose a subset, $A$ of $\Omega$ , such that $\min(\Var(A), \Var(\Omega \setminus A))$ is maximised? Here, $\Var$ is the variance function.
I have used python to look at examples ranging up to $n = 17$, but it's not demonstrating any clear patterns.
Here is an example:
$A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ then
$$
\Var(A) = \frac{\sum_{x \in A} (x - 2.5)^2}{4}
$$ and similarly for $\Var(\Omega \setminus A)$.

This question could use some more context/information.  What is your motivation here/where did this question come from?  What do the sets look like for the largish values of $n$ that you've tried?

@KevinP.Costello I am working on a computer science program, and I believe to achieve what I want optimally I will have to select subsets that satisfy the property specified in the question.

Didn't you (or some other user) recently pose this question, with $n=136$?

I'm not sure of the precise answer to your question.  I suspect a greedy algorithm that chooses the next number for $A$ or $\Omega\setminus A$ based on which has the lower variation at that stage will be asymptotically optimal.  Also, it might be optimal in the limit to choose $A$ so that the mean for both $A$ and $\Omega\setminus A$ is approximately $\frac{n+1}{2}$.  Here's an example:
$$A: 1, n, 4, n-3, 5, n-4, 8, n-7, 9, n-8, \ldots$$
$$\Omega\setminus A: 2, n-1, 3, n-2, 6, n-5, 7, n-6, \ldots$$
At each stage, we attempt to select the next pair of unpicked numbers that maximizes the variance of the subset with the lowest current variance.  I'm curious how your python program would score this solution!

I think this is good intuition because it approximately matches some of the sets I got when I brute forced it
